# Cocoapods project.pbxproj merge conflicts

Tags: ios, xcode, git, merge, cocoapods

I have spent a long time looking for an answer regarding merge conflicts with project.pbxproj files. My merge conflicts mainly occur with Cocoapods. It seems that if I add a pod on a branch, then try to merge it into another, many many merge conflict arise in the project.pbxproj file of my Pods project. I would simply go trough and fix these conflicts manually, but there are way to many for this to be reasonable. Has anyone else encountered this problem and found a reasonable solution. This issue has plagued me for sometime now and I am only asking this question as a last resort. After creating a couple of new features on separate branches, having this much trouble including them into my project is very frustrating. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

As long as you're not making changes, which you probably shouldn't be, to the `Pods.xcodeproj` file, then the source of truth is always what is generated with `pod install`. Therefore if there are many conflicts you can just delete the project and regenerate it.

Comment: Are you recommending removing the Pods.xcodeproj, then merge the files, then regenerate it or delete them, regenerate them then merge. I have tried both and this just moves the conflict from the Pods.xcodeproj project.pbxproj to my main profiles project.pbxproj.

Comment: I'm recommending when you see a merge conflict, as long as you haven't edited them yourselves, delete the conflicted files and run `pod install` again.

Comment: @KeithSmiley Thank you for your comment here, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this on a fairly regular basis.  I have a recipe that works *most* of the time.  We use Git-flow, so are typically trying to merge feature branches into `develop`.  Memory being what it is, often the first time we notice this is when GitHub warns of a conflict.

1. Commit (or stash) all outstanding work  on your local feature branch.
2. Run `pod deintegrate` ([docs here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_deintegrate))
3. Commit the branch.  It’s temporarily in an unusable state.  This will be resolved momentarily.
4. Switch to the latest `develop`
5. Again, run `pod deintegrate`
6. Commit changes to `develop`.  Don’t push these changes up to origin. This commit will be deleted shortly.
7. Switch back to your working branch.
8. Merge in your local `develop`.  Hopefully this will be conflict free.
9. Run `pod install`, run the apps and check that everything works as expected.
10. Commit the merge.  Delete the local `develop` commit (i.e. `git reset` to origin)
11. Push working branch changes.

You may also want to consider using a hook to prevent pushes of integrated projects.  This puts the onus on the developer to `pod deintegrate` before pushing changes up (and also requires other developers to `pod deintegrate` before merging *from* `develop`) but does remove one potential source of conflicts if using a cloud repo provider that manages your workflow like GitHub.

It's also worth splitting out file-add operations into their own commit to reduce the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Following by this guild: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3093

For CocoaPods to say that message, the project will have `<<<<<<<, >>>>>>>` or `=======` on a line indicating it has a conflict which hasn't been resolved.

It is possible that there is still the conflict markers and the file is still in a conflict (git only says it's resolved because it was told it has been resolved regardless of the conflict markers).

You can find them in your file by running the following:

```
grep -E '<<<<<<<|>>>>>>>|=======' /path/to/project/project.pbxproj
```